# Can't subtract two CGPoint operands in Swift 3 error

Tags: swift3

I’m developing a game in `Swift 3` with `SpriteKit`.

I’m having some problems with the conditional below.

```
if (personaje.position - lastTouchLocation).length() < pjPixelsPerSecond * CGFloat(dt){
    velocity = CGPoint.zero
} else {
  moveSprite(sprite: personaje, velocity: velocity)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'CGPoint' operands.

How can I subtract these two variables?

And I got:

```
var personaje = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "personajee")
var velocity = CGPoint.zero
var lastTouchLocation = CGPoint.zero
… 

func sceneTouched (touchLocation: CGPoint) {
    lastTouchLocation = touchLocation
    movePjToLocation(location: touchLocation)

}
```

Comment: Have you defined a `-` overload for `CGPoint`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define by yourself the `-` operator for `CGPoint`. Declare the function outside of any class's scope, so it will be visible in your whole project.

```
// Declare `-` operator overload function
func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint { 
    return CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
}
// TEST
let point1 = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5)
print(point1 - point2) //prints (5.0, 5.0)
```

Comment: More CGPoint tricks at https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/master/SKTUtils/CGPoint%2BExtensions.swift

Answer (score -1):

Using `CGVector`:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        return CGVector(dx: lhs.x - rhs.x, dy: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**

Here is a version calculating the abs value:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: abs(lhs.x - rhs.x),
                y: abs(lhs.y - rhs.y))
    }
}
```